# Postback problem? Not getting data back from DB

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm not getting back data from my DB like I'm expecting. I know that I can get data from the DB because I have other functions working. With this page, what I'm trying to do is the following:

If no postback, then I would like it to echo "No Category Selected"

If a category has been chosen, then I would like for it to get that data from the DB and show it on the page. I'm sure I can do this all in one view, I'm just not doing something right. Can someone help please?

the error i'm getting is:

A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Trying to get property of non-object Filename: views/category_view.php Line Number: 25

as for db schema:

table: **'business'** id, busname, busowner, busaddress, busicyt, busstate, buszip, busphone, webaddress, category, featured, userid.

table: **'category'** id, catname, catdesc.

table: **'photos'** id, photoname, photolocation, busid, userid.

table: **'specials'** id, specname, specdesc, busid, userid.

table: **'videos'** id, title, link, busid.

Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/AQqcvnAb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure at all what exactly is or isn't working for you. I tried this locally, and It is echoing "no category selected" correctly.

View:

```
<?php 
echo form_open('/site/categories');
echo form_fieldset(); ?>
<legend>Choose the Category of Business you are interested in.</legend>
<select name="catSelect">
<?php 
foreach ($catList->result() as $row){
    echo '<option value='.$row->id.'>'.$row->catname.'</option>';
}
echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit');
echo form_fieldset_close();
echo form_close(); 
?>
<table id="businessTable" class="tablesorter">
<thead><tr><th>Business Name</th><th>Photos</th><th>Videos</th><th>Specials</th></tr></thead>
<?php 
if(count($serviceVendors) > 0){
    foreach ($serviceVendors as $row){
        echo '<tr><td>'.$row->busname.'</td><td>';
        if(isset($row->photoname)){
                echo "photoname is set";
            }else{
                echo "photoname not set";
            }
            echo '</td><td>';
            if(isset($row->title)){
                echo "title set";
            }else{
                echo "title not set";
            }
            echo '</td><td>';
            if(isset($row->specname)){
                echo "specname set";
            }else{
                echo "specname not set";
            }
            echo '</td></tr>';
        }
    }else{
        echo "no category selected";
    }
?>
</table>
```

If you can be a little more specific (and post a db schema), I'll try harder.

---

OK. The problem is in your category_view:

```
<?php if(count($businessList) > 0) : foreach ($businessList as $svrow): ?>
```

needs to be:

```
<?php if(count($businessList) > 0) : foreach ($businessList->result() as $svrow): ?>
```

without the `->result()` identifier it doesn't assign the object to svrow. 
So with this line, in place `echo $svrow->busname;` will echo the business name as expected.

Comment: the error i'm getting is:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: views/category_view.php

Line Number: 25

as for db schema:

table: business
id, busname, busowner, busaddress, busicyt, busstate, buszip, busphone, webaddress, category, featured, userid

table: category
id, catname, catdesc

table: photos
id, photoname, photolocation, busid, userid

table: specials
id, specname, specdesc, busid, userid

table: videos
id, title, link, busid

Comment: I dunno, man. It looks like you're missing some methods in your model (frontPageList(), tank_auth()??). Again from here the category selection is working correctly. I'm not sure what line is causing your error (pastebin isn't clear). That error is to do with not looping through  the returned object correctly, if memory serves. Try print_r 'ing the vars you're trying to get into the view.

What exactly is on views/category_view.php Line Number: 25 

What do you get if you try and `print_r($var_on_line_25);`? Is it a mysqlobject? array?

Comment: line 25 is: <td><?=$row->busname?></td>

Comment: I just want it to do something simple. If a query hasn't been made i want it to show that a query hasn't been made. if one is made I want it to show the data from the db that has been queried. :(

Comment: Ah. It might be conflicting with the other foreach var name. Change `foreach ($serviceVendors as $row):` to `foreach ($serviceVendors as $svRow):` and `<?=$row->busname?>` to `<?=$svRow->busname?>`. See what happens. If that doesn't work, what does `print_r($svRow->busname);` give?

Comment: ok, i tried it. here's what i got: Resource id #31Resource id #48Array
(
)
Array
(
)
01

Comment: It looks like another array is being returned from the db. Did you try looping through $row->busname?

I can't reproduce your problem here because I don't have all the pieces. If you want, zip up your system folder and put a db dump in there too and upload it to rapidhsare or something.

Comment: Thank you, that seemed to work. I'm at least able to see data now. My code to check for postback doesn't seem to be working correctly, no matter what, the catID=6? Here's the code: if (!isset($_POST['catID']))
  {
   $catID = '6';
  }
  else
  {
   $catID = $_POST['catID'];
  }

Comment: how did you know I should add "->result()"? Under what circumstances is that required?

Comment: Try changing `$data['businessList']  = $this->Business_model->categoryPageList($catSelect);` to `$data['businessList']  = $this->Business_model->categoryPageList($catID);` in your site.php controller. See http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html re: result()

Comment: Weird, I changed it to this: $this->load->model('Business_model');
  if (!isset($_POST['catID']))
  {
   $catID = '*';
  }
  else
  {
   $catID = $_POST['catID'];
  }

and it works now.